# AngularJS with System.Web.Routing

Tags: angularjs, routes

This is a question about routing for an AngularJS app.  It is not using MVC, it does use WebAPI for the backend (these routes work fine).

I'm using the VS SPA template as a baseline: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83

The problem I'm having is that my DefaultRouteHandler seems to always get hit before my angular defined routes.  So for example I have a route that is /wageagreement/new, but the .cshtml file lives in /views/wageagreement/detail.  My angular route is defined as follows in app.js:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('wageagreement-new', {
            url: '/wageagreement/new',
            templateUrl: '/views/wageagreement/detail',
            controller: 'wageAgreementDetailsCtrl'
        })
```

If I go to the page /wageagreement/new, my DefaultRouteHandler (see below) is first hit and the filepath is /wageagreement/new.  Because this file doesn't exist I get a 404 error returned.  THEN my angular path seems to kick in and the page loads fine from /view/wageagreement/detail.  So for every page I get the error 404 flash up then I get the right page.  Is there any way to make this work?  I'm starting to think maybe my .cshtml files must match my routes to make it work.

```
public class DefaultRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // Use cases:
        //     ~/            -> ~/views/index.cshtml
        //     ~/about       -> ~/views/about.cshtml or ~/views/about/index.cshtml
        //     ~/views/about -> ~/views/about.cshtml
        //     ~/xxx         -> ~/views/404.cshtml
        var filePath = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;

        if (filePath == "~/")
        {
            filePath = "~/views/touranalysis/index.cshtml";
        }
        else
        {
            if (!filePath.StartsWith("~/views/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                filePath = filePath.Insert(2, "views/");
            }

            if (!filePath.EndsWith(".cshtml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                filePath = filePath += ".cshtml";
            }
        }

        var handler = WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath(filePath); // returns NULL if .cshtml file wasn't found

        if (handler == null)
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("templateUrl", "/views/404");
            handler = WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath("~/views/404.cshtml");
        }
        else
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("templateUrl", filePath.Substring(1, filePath.Length - 8));
        }

        return handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm about to create my first Angular project and I'm not sure if I should use a third-party template, go with MVC, SPA, Web API, etc.

Answer (score 8):

The VS SPA template (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83) is doing double routing. It's not insufficient. It's just wrong. Non of the direct links work except the root one.

If you want to use Angular routing  all you have to do is to make DefaultRouteHandler class look like this

```
public class DefaultRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return WebPageHttpHandler.CreateFromVirtualPath("~/views/index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Basicaly re-route everithing to your Angular main page and let the Angular routing do the job.

Comment: thanks this works great for me. I think the OP should accept this answer. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I am no Angular specialist but will share my experience:

Your URL doesn't have to match the view's actual location, but it does need enough correlation to that location so that you can build B from A. In our application the Angular router's `url` and `templateUrl` practically match, and the server side handler is building from the URL something like `"~/Views/{url}.cshtml"` Your server seems to be doing this already.

This still loads your content twice though, once server side and once via Angular's routing. To avoid this, you could use the Angular `$templateCache` mechanism upon Angular startup (we did it in our module's `run()` method), something like so:

```
    var view = angular.element('#ui-view');
    $templateCache.put(view.data('tmpl-url'), view.html());
```

This will read the content of the server rendered HTML and cache it, so that when your app needs to call it client-side (immediately after) it will find the view in the cache and not trigger another call. I do not know if the view is being then re-rendered, you might want to check that. We currently don't see any flicker, but this might be because we've only used it so far on the relatively powerful dev machine.

Naturally this requires the `data-tmpl-url` attribute on your view, populated with `data-tmpl-url="@Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["TemplateUrl"]"` but I believe this comes built-in with your template. If not - add it. I see in your code that tour server is already populating this data token.

Note that we use AngularUI, hence `#ui-view`. If you're using the built-in AngularJS router then replace that with `#ng-view`.